# Slow execution of linux service mtab.sh

Tags: linux, speed, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to speed up the boot time of my raspberry pi with raspbian. With the program bootchart (which makes a graph of the running time of the services at start up) I have seen that the mtab.sh script takes a long time to finish, almost 5 seconds (and yes, for my puropose it's a long time).

Do you know why it takes so much? Is there any way to speed up it?

Thank you!